# Cronjob won't trigger .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, cron, sh

I have made this Cronjob that should run some tests. My script works, but cronjob won't trigger it.

Cronjob looks like this:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh cd ~/Desktop/abc.sh
```

I want it to run every minute, just for testing purposes.

And my script is:

```
while read LINE; do curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code} $LINE\n" "$LINE"; done < todo | tee test_results.txt
```

I can't even find the solution on google or youtube.

Comment: You are running `cd`, that is, change directory, and changing directory to what looks like a file.

Comment: You have a broken line for your cron job. Remove the leading asterisk and slash before the number one.

Comment: Is this correct?

```
1 * * * * /bin/sh /Desktop/abc.sh

```

Comment: Try replacing `/Desktop/abc.sh` to absolute path of same file

Comment: 1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/otto/Desktop/abc.sh still not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added #!/bin/bash to your script, then your cronjob should look like:

```
* * * * * ~/Desktop/abc.sh
```

Or

```
* * * * * /home/USER/Desktop/abc.sh
```

In the first case you have to run cronjob from the same user where of the Desktop folder.